# Replace Spaces and . in filename with Underscores

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129486/2000557 's example and modified the script for a folder of video files.

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=."
Set "Replace=_"

For %%a in (*.avi) Do (
Set "File=%%~a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

For %%a in (*.mkv) Do (
Set "File=%%~a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

For %%a in (*.mp4) Do (
Set "File=%%~a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

Can anyone explain why this also replaces the last dot in the filename (that is a part of the extension) into an underscore. this feels like I was given the fish and not taught how to fish. this script works, but sadly it replaces the last period also.
I'd like to use the script without having to turn on Hide Extensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch-file for replacing dots with spaces in file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558996/batch-file-for-replacing-dots-with-spaces-in-file-names)

Comment: You could use my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). The solution is then as simple as `jren "[. ](?=.*\.)" "_" /fm "*.avi|*.mkv|*.mp4"`

Answer (score 2):

The substitution is overall and can't be limited.

The workaround is easy just use the name without extension for file and append the original extension - this way only one for (for each substitution) is needed.

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%A in ("*.*.avi" "*.*.mkv" "*.*.mp4") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nA"
    Ren "%%A" "!File:.=_!%%~xA" 2>NUL
)

For %%A in ("* *.avi" "* *.mkv" "* *.mp4") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nA"
    Ren "%%A" "!File: =_!%%~xA" 2>NUL
)
```

Or this version

```
For %%A in (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4) Do (
    Set "File=%%~nA"
    Set "File=!File: =_!"
    Set "File=!File:.=_!"
    If "%%~nA" neq "!File!" Ren "%%A" "!File!%%~xA"
)
```

I'm not shure which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this batch script :

```bat
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "FileType=avi mp4 mkv"
Call :Search_Replace " " "." "!FileType!"
Call :Search_Replace "." "_" "!FileType!"
Timeout -1 & exit
::********************************************************
:Search_Replace <Pattern> <Replace> <FileType>
Set "Pattern=%~1"
Set "Replace=%~2"
@For %%# in (%~3) do (
    For %%a in (*.%%#) Do (
        Set "File=%%~na"
            ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!%%~xa"
    )
)
Exit /b
::********************************************************
```