# Windows CLI use FINDSTR to return only everything after the string

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have my CLI query set to:

```
c:\>findstr /c:"TOTAL" Invoice.txt 
TOTAL 80:00
```

However I only want the search query to return everything after the query:

```
80.00
```

Also if I use wild in the filename it returns the whole file name then the line. I want it again to only return everything after the string and not the filename as I want to pipe the results into a text file.

```
c:\>findstr /c:"TOTAL" *.txt
Invoice - Copy (2).txt:TOTAL 120.00
Invoice - Copy (3).txt:TOTAL 110.00
Invoice - Copy (4).txt:TOTAL 100.00
Invoice - Copy.txt:TOTAL 90.00
Invoice.txt:TOTAL 80.00
```

Ideally I run my command and just get the following

```
120.00
110.00
100.00
90.00
80.00
```

Ideas on how to do this? Powershell or CMD is fine. At the moment I am going to put it all into a batch script but a ps script would work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output of a command, use a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /c:"TOTAL" *.txt') do echo %%a
```

Given, your data is always as your example (line is exactly `TOTAL xxx.xx` and there is no other `TOTAL` in the files (may want to use `findstr /b`))

(batch-syntax. To use it directly on command line, replace every `%%a` with `%a`)

**EDIT** a bit more complicated with spaces in the filenames. Do it in two steps: first get the pure data splitting by `:` (`"tokens=2 delims=:" %%a`) and in a second `for` split by space (standard delimiter) (`"tokens=2" %%b`) :

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "TOTAL" *.txt') do (
  for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ("%%a") do echo %%b
)
```

(a bit more code, but better than messing with the original data (renaming files))

Comment: Was close but not quite there, I had to first remove the white spaces

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270453/how-to-remove-spaces-from-file-names-in-bulk

  in the filenames then your for /f loop worked.

Comment: sorry, I missed the spaces in the filenames. See my edit please.

Answer (score 0):

A [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) can capture the output of the `findstr` command line. After having stored each line in an environment variable, [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) can be applied in a way that everything up to and including `:` + `TOTAL` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> becomes removed:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /C:"TOTAL" "*.txt"') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    echo(!LINE:*:TOTAL =!
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents ;-) . The first for can be a simple one just to iterate the file names.

```
@Echo off
( For %%A in (*.txt
  ) Do For /f "tokens=2" %%B in ('findstr /B /C:"TOTAL" "%%A"'
  ) Do Echo:%%B
) >All-Totals.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Also easy in PowerShell.

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content .\Invoice.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '.*TOTAL (.*)' } | % { $matches[1] }
120.00
110.00
100.00
90.00
80.00

PS C:\src\t> cat .\Invoice.txt | where { $_ -match '.*TOTAL (.*)' } | % { $matches[1] }
120.00
110.00
100.00
90.00
80.00
```